# A constant gaze

Tags: mathematics, proof-without-words

What this infinite spiral seems to be gazing at goes without saying.

[image]

Yet, to go on and on heedlessly as if trying to prove something,
let’s just say
it represents an equality with a well-known mathematical constant,
though in a needlessly circumspect manner.

***What equality is represented?***

<sub>(How this diagram works is described in
[***Wrap-up: the making of* A constant gaze**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/98023))</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It reminds me of

> [the continued fraction of $\sqrt2$](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/SqContinuedFraction.shtml)

Why?

> If the width of the largest square is 1, the longest green line has a length of $\sqrt2$. To get its continued fraction, we subtract the entire part (1) and we're left with $\sqrt2-1$ (the width of the remaining rectangle). Its height is 1, and this rectangle is congruent to one with width 1 and height $\sqrt2 + 1$. The entire part of that is 2 (the squares at the top and bottom) and the pattern continues.

So the equality the author is hinting at might be

> $$\sqrt 2 = 1 + \frac1{2+\frac1{2+\frac1{2+\frac1{...}}}}$$

Comment: Note from poser: The diagram is more than a hint.
It calculates the coefficients in a way that works for all numbers.

Comment: You're right, it works for other numbers too. Nice, I've studied mathematics but never came across this particular construction. About the formatting: it doesn't show up raw, but e.g. on smaller screens the main question looked awkward because it doesn't fit on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

**Wrap-up: the making of
[*A constant gaze*](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97516)**

*This is not a solution to the puzzle but provides notes from its poser.
 This type of answer has been
 [approved by the community](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5420/).*

***Caution:** This post contains information about the solution.*

---

**How this puzzle’s diagram works in general**
is demonstrated below
with a pre-posting version of the puzzle, representing the
[continued-fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction)
coefficients of a mathematical constant
different from that in the posted puzzle.
For the different constant, here is the discarded diagram
(at left) beside (at right)
a copy with its squares rearranged
to show them as a decreasing sequence of additions
that approximate the overall rectangle’s area more and more completely.

[image]

The counts of squares at each scale exactly match the
continued-fraction coefficients of
[√3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_3),
as is true of diagrams like this for all continued fractions.

[image]

Two well-known constants other than √3
were also considered for this puzzle,
[φ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)
and
[√2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2),
whose continued-fraction diagrams are simpler than that of √3.

[image]

The diagram for φ was discarded
as it is altogether *too* well known.
To stay with √3 remained extremely tempting as,
among these candidates,
its continued fraction is the most intricate
and its diagram is the most puzzling.

But the puzzle went to the constant
whose diagram allowed for the best clueing.
That clueing is the set of arcs that emphasize how simply
the ratio of sizes from level to level relates to the ratio
of lengths of a square’s side and diagonal.
And what a nice relief from straight lines and octagonal angles.